# Detect and uninstall antivirus

Tags: powershell, uninstallation, antivirus

I have been trying to make a powershell script to detect what antivirus software is installed, and then uninstall it.

I have been able to detect what antivirus is installed using WMI.

I cant find a way to uninstall antivirus software via powershell however.

Is there a way to do this?
Hope you guys can help.

The script i use to detect antivirus:

```
function Get-AntivirusName { 
[cmdletBinding()]     
param ( 
[string]$ComputerName = "$env:computername" , 
$Credential 
) 
    BEGIN  
        { 
            $wmiQuery = "SELECT * FROM AntiVirusProduct" 
        } 
    PROCESS  
        {    
            $AntivirusProduct = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SecurityCenter2" -Query $wmiQuery  @psboundparameters         
            [array]$AntivirusNames = $AntivirusProduct.displayName       
            Switch($AntivirusNames) {
                {$AntivirusNames.Count -eq 0}{"No Antivirus installed";Continue}
                {$AntivirusNames.Count -eq 1 -and $_ -eq "Windows Defender"} {"Only Windows Defender is installed!";Continue}
                {$_ -ne "Windows Defender"} {"Antivirus installed ($_)."}
           }
} 
     END { 
         } 
}

$av = Get-AntivirusName

Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($av,'Antivirus')
```

Comment: You've not shown any of your own code or any indication you've tried researching/searching for a solution. (Always include your code even if it doesn't work!) I'd recommend reading [ask] and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) as at the moment your question is missing the basics that are expected when asking a question. Your question is likely to be downvoted and closed until you include the basics.

Comment: I havnt made anything to do it yet, because i cant find a way to do it.
I do have a code to detect Antivirus software, but didt think it was relevent to talk about ways you can do it. My bad if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, from https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/3161-detect-and-remove-software-powershell:

> ```
> ################################################
> # Powershell Detect and Remove software script #
> #                                              #
> # V1.0 - Gav                                   #
> ################################################
> # - Edit the Variables below and launch the    #
> #   script as an account that can access the   #
> #   machines.                                  #
> # - Script will check that logs exist and      #
> #   create them if needed.                     #
> ################################################
>
> cls
>
> #VARIABLES - EDIT BELOW
>     $software = "INSERT SOFTWARE HERE" # - Enter the name as it appears from WMIC query. WMIC PRODUCT NAME
>     $textfile = "C:\path\pclist.txt"
>     $Successlogfile = "C:\path\Done_Machines.txt"
>     $Errorlogfile = "C:\path\Failed_Machines.txt"
>
> #Date Calculation for Logs
>     $today = Get-Date
>     $today = $today.ToString("dddd (dd-MMMM-yyyy)")
>
> #Load PC's From Text File
>     $computers = Get-Content "$textfile"
>
> #Check if Log Files Exist
>     If (Test-Path $Successlogfile) {
>         Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Success Log File Exists, Results will be appended"
>                                    }
>         else
>                                    {
>         Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Success Log File does not exist, creating log file"
>         New-Item -path $Successlogfile -ItemType file
>                                    }
>
>     If (Test-Path $Errorlogfile) {
>         Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Error Log File Exists, Results will be appended"
>                                    }
>         else
>                                    {
>         Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Error Log File does not exist, creating log file"
>         New-Item -path $Successlogfile -ItemType file
>                                    }
>
>
>
> #Run Ping Test and Uninstall if turned on
>     foreach ($computer in $computers) {
>         If (Test-Connection -quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -computername $computer -count 2) 
>         {
>                 Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$Computer is responding, Attempting Uninstall of $Software"
>                 Add-Content $Successlogfile "`n$today`n$Computer`n"
>                 Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Product -ComputerName $computer | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $software} | ForEach-Object { $_.Uninstall()}
>         }
>             else
>         {
>                 Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "$Computer is not responding"
>                 Add-Content $Errorlogfile "`n$today`n$Computer`n"
>         }
>                                        }
> ```

Comment: If you're going to copy and paste [someone else's code without attribution](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/3161-detect-and-remove-software-powershell), at least spend the time to format it so it actually displays properly.

Comment: @JamesC. It was properly edited.... And I do mention Its not my work...

Comment: You know there's an [edit history for your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50327127/revisions)? So anyone can see that neither of those things were true when I commented and edited your post almost two weeks ago.